# ASP.NET validation group disappears (in Sitefinity user control)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, user-controls, sitefinity

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Go!" 
        ValidationGroup="EmailForm" onclick="btnSend_Click" />

WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$cphLeft$C001$btnSend', '', true, '**MISSING??**',
'', false, true))
```

Above first the ASP.NET code we use to put a button on a form. Below that is the code that is rendered. Where i put **MISSING??** , i was expecting the ValidationGroup...

One detail is that we are using this in a user control that is used in Sitefinity. But, as that is just a ASP.NET CMS, i can't think of anything special that influences this type of code.

Any ideas on how this can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but by default, Sitefinity pages have Viewstate disabled. Open the Properties of the page (under the Actions menu in the list of pages in the backend) and check the box to enable viewstate and let me know if that resolves the issue.

hope this is helpful!

Comment: Hi Josh, i already checked this and the viewstate is turned on. I played with in, but turning it on or off doesn't make a difference.

Comment: can you run this code in a webform in the app (like test.aspx) and verify that it does work on a standalone page? if it does, i'd suggest you send the code via a support ticket to the team so they can see why SF is causing a different result.

Comment: Somehow this error was only there when using Buttons. Pretty strange, but we switched to LinkButtons, and the problem was gone. Not the way i'd like to solve this, but it was the way to keep a client happy and going..